# Finding entries an entry is related to in Playa

Tags: playa

I'm not sure how best to ask this question, hopefully I do it justice...

On this page: http://www.aribalive.com/las-vegas-2014/agenda I use Playa to relate breakout sessions to specific agenda items (called Rotations).  When you click on the Rotations, the list of sessions associated with that agenda item is revealed.  Agenda items are a channel on their own, and Sessions are another channel.  This is all working correctly.

Now, on the Breakout Session page (http://www.aribalive.com/las-vegas-2014/breakouts), I need to add an additional filter for Rotation, so as I'm looping through each Breakout Session in the channel loop, I need a way to find out which rotation (or rotations) each individual session has been associated with.  The Breakout page doesn't run a channel entry loop for the Agenda channel, and I'd really rather not run that for each individual breakout session since that would be massively inefficient... I'm hoping there's a Playa module tag that can take breakout session entry ID that will render data on entries it's been associated with...

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: (I don't have enough rep here to answer my own question, but I figured it out)

{exp:playa:parents channel='live_agenda' backspace='1'}{entry_id},{/exp:playa:parents}

When I put this in the context of the channel entry loop, it renders the entry_ids for any of the Session rotations it's associated with.  Easy :)  I think my problem was just one of reversing how the relationships work...  Anyway, there's the answer :)